# Bug in mobile version

Tags: discussion, bug, chat, mobile-web

**Main question**

I recently answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328666/finite-number-of-atoms). I subsequently engaged on a huge comment thread which was eventually [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24925/discussion-on-answer-by-mickg-finite-number-of-atoms) by Daniel Fischer, since it spanned 43 comments. I tried to chat, but my mobile simply won't let me chat via Internet, complaining I «must be logged in to chat» when I am perfectly logged in to the main site, and when I click on «logged in» I am redirected to [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4knwS.png) and nothing else can be done. The app doesn't let me chat either because the options for opening the chat link are only Internet, Chrome and Firefox. What is going on here? Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or a [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design)? )

**Extra**

Also, how do I put a formatted tag into the question via markdown? You know, the likes of the {status-completed} [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6066/42315).

This was added to the question only to solve a problem which came up in typing the question. I surely didn't expect an answer only addressing this point. I rather expected an answer about the main question and a comment about the extra, or even just an edit to my question making the tag appear so that I could subsequently see the code and maybe edit the extra out. I hope I will get such an answer, because this question was not the extra, so I cannot accept AlexR's answer about the extra, though I upvoted it.

Comment: Like ([meta-tag:status-completed])?

Comment: Exactly. `[tag: status-complete]` didn't work for me.

Comment: It's `[meta-tag:status-completed]` for meta tags.

Comment: Is it the blank space after the colon that made my attempt not work?

Comment: I don't know, but I think it might. Let's just test it: [meta-tag: status-completed].
.... Jup. That's the culprit.

Comment: [Markdown help on tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tags). See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10873/how-to-use-tagtag-name-for-tags-of-the-meta-site

Comment: BTW I don't think it is very good to ask two independent question in the same post;.

Comment: The title clears the main question. The "also" part was an aside emerging from a problem in the question post. I thought it could be a little extra to the answer. I didn't expect to get answers only about that.

Answer (score 3):

The "also" part:

`[meta-tag:tag-name]`, such as [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design).
For main tags use
`[tag:tag-name]`, such as [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis).

Note that TeX.SE has curly braces around the tag where we have parentheses by site design. In comments the markdown will only add a link, so adding parentheses is up to you.